# Reconnect Authenticator with Google account for a second time

Tags: google-account, google-authenticator

My account had *2-step verification* enabled and associated with the Authenticator App on my phone.

Yesterday I reformatted it and now I'm installing the apps again. Everything is setup but the Google Authenticator App looks for a barcode, and I cannot find in the *2-step verification* steps. What I'd like to do is re-associate my account with the Google Authenticator App **without** turning off 2 step auth and back on again.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's why you should always take data backup of Authenticator app using Titanium Backup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, there is no way to re-associate a phone. It looks like your option is to disassociate/re-associate.

Comment: I don't see an "add a phone" option?

Comment: Hmmm...I guess I mis-parsed the "add a backup" link. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ah, yeah.  I experimented by trying to add the same phone as the backup, and of course it didn't work.

Comment: Since there were no other options, this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** You can re-add the same phone by going to https://www.google.com/accounts/SmsAuthConfig and hitting the Edit link beside "Android" (the Mobile Application field).  Oddly enough, this link didn't work for me in Chrome but it did in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Would it? I've already logged into my account on the web browser of my computer. I'd understand if I were logged out and I'd need the authenticator code to login again (and a vicious circle). But if I'm able to turn off 2-step and turn it on again, the security is already bypassed.

Comment: @Luciano Your web log in has been verified via the two-step process already, though.  Your phone cannot be re-verified via the two-step process since one of the steps no longer works.  Your web login can safely turn off two-step since it was verified with two-step; that's not bypassing security at all.

Comment: Now that I think about it, since your web log-in has been double-checked it should be allowed to authenticate devices.  I experimented further; my answer has been revised.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I couldn't do this. I ended up deassociating and reassociating the phone. Luckily it didn't erase my application-specific passwords.